# Is there a way to fill in missing values in a data frame in a list format as the last value of the list in the previous row?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

At the moment, I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    date         B  C   D   E
0   04/06/2019  258 994 761 [1, 46, 36, 7457, 456]
1   05/06/2019  748 181 565 [22, 3453, 45]
2   06/06/2019  357 290  98 []
2   07/06/2019  185 876 107 [4976, 46, 57, 7, 3]
3   08/06/2019  241 386 728 [4, 6457, 4]
4   09/06/2019  516 579 596 [65]
5   10/06/2019   96 579 596 []
6   11/06/2019  847 109 279 []
```

What I need to achieve is this:

```
    date         B  C   D   E
0   04/06/2019  258 994 761 [1, 46, 36, 7457, 456]
1   05/06/2019  748 181 565 [22, 3453, 45]
2   06/06/2019  357 290  98 [45]
2   07/06/2019  185 876 107 [4976, 46, 57, 7, 3]
3   08/06/2019  241 386 728 [4, 6457, 4]
4   09/06/2019  516 579 596 [65]
5   10/06/2019   96 579 596 [65]
6   11/06/2019  847 109 279 [65]
```

I know that for numeric data I could use something like this:

```
df.E = df.E.fillna(method='ffill')
```

But I don't now what I can do for a list. Can you help me?

Comment: What's the logic of filling in the empty brackets?

Comment: where does the 22 come from in row 1 of your expected output?

Comment: That's what I noticed too, what is the "condition" basically, as to what number to populate the list with?

Comment: Well, this list is the time that it takes to process each batch inside a snapshot. The empty list should mean that the time did not changed since the last batch processed. For this reason, I need to fill in with the last value in the list. Afterwards, I convert this to numeric in two types of variables: one that takes the maximum value of each list and one that it takes the average value. This would be my next step: df.E = df.E.apply(lambda row: max(row) if row != [] else np.nan)

Comment: Sorry, the 22 was a mistake. I fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get last values of lists and then forward filling missing values:

```
s = df.E.apply(lambda x: [x[-1]] if len(x) > 0 else np.nan)

df.E = df.E.mask(s.isna(), s.ffill())
print (df)
         date    B    C    D                       E
0  04/06/2019  258  994  761  [1, 46, 36, 7457, 456]
1  05/06/2019  748  181  565          [22, 3453, 45]
2  06/06/2019  357  290   98                    [45]
2  07/06/2019  185  876  107    [4976, 46, 57, 7, 3]
3  08/06/2019  241  386  728            [4, 6457, 4]
4  09/06/2019  516  579  596                    [65]
5  10/06/2019   96  579  596                    [65]
6  11/06/2019  847  109  279                    [65]
```

Comment: Thank you again @jezrael! Always helping me out! :)